# How to implement sumifs with multiple conditions including date ranges in python?

Tags: python, pandas

i would like to implement a sumifs equivalent calculation in python but not sure how to do it.

```
data={'product_id':['a','a','b','b'],
      'start':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,1)],
      'end':[datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4),datetime.date(2016,1,3)],
      'store':['X','Y','X','Y']}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

sales={'date':[datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
      datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
      datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4),
      datetime.date(2016,1,1),datetime.date(2016,1,2),datetime.date(2016,1,3),datetime.date(2016,1,4)],
      'product':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
       'store':['X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'],
       'sales':[20,30,59,110,30,40,80,20,80,59,110,30,40,80,20,10]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)
```

I want to summarize the sales for each of the product by store per the time range defined in df. In excel I can use sumifs function but not sure how to do this in python. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: `...but not sure how to do it. ... Can someone help me?` - Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page.    [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your date ranges to the sales data the look for records between the ranges and do a groupby/sum on that.

```
df = df2.merge(df, left_on=['store','product'], right_on=['store', 'product_id'])
df.loc[df['date'].between(df['start'], df['end'])].groupby(['store','product'])['sales'].sum().reset_index(name='total_sales')
```

Output

```
  store product  total_sales
0     X       a          219
1     X       b          100
2     Y       a          249
3     Y       b          140
```